# Parsing text and return hostname before period with PHP

Tags: php

```
$hostname = "abc.domain.com"
```

I just want "abc" and nothing after it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`explode()`](http://php.net/explode):

```
$parts = explode('.', $hostname);
// $parts[0]
```

Answer (score 2):

With [`substr`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.substr.php) and [`strpos`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strpos.php):

```
$host = substr($hostname, 0, strpos($hostname, '.'));
```

or maybe better, [`strstr`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strstr.php):

```
$host = strstr($hostname, '.', true);
```

[There are a lot of functions available to process strings.](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.strings.php)

Comment: +1, for the reason that its error proof as if `strpos` returns false it will make the `substr` return an empty string.

Comment: @RobertPitt: Depends, maybe the whole string should be returned then? But that is for the OP to decide and depends on the possible input values.

Answer (score 1):

Will it always have a subdomain?

If so, you can just do

```
$parts = explode('.', $hostname);
$subdomain = $parts[0];
```

If there might not be a subdomain

```
$parts = explode('.', $hostname);
$subdomain = count($parts) == 3 ? $parts[0] : NULL;
```